# How do I automatically add a user to a Backdrop (or Drupal) role?

Tags: drupal, groups, permissions, backdrop

I figured out how to [automatically add a newly-created user to a group](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/33542/12) when they fill out a contribution or event page, but I want to add them to a Backdrop role as well.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

First, go to your modules listing and enable "CiviGroup Roles Sync":
[image]

Next, go to Drupal's **Configuration menu » CiviCRM » CiviGroup Roles Sync » Add association rule**:
[image]

From here, you can set the CiviCRM group that corresponds to the Backdrop/Drupal role:
[image]

Note this only works when contacts are newly added to the group (or role).  However, you can manually synchronize in the configuration settings.